# Spotfire 6.5: How to check exact value in Find function

Tags: listbox, calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a document property which is being used as a filter for the reports. It is a multi select List box. I have created a calculated field (flag) which uses this expression:

```
if(find(Upper(Concatenate([Col1],' | ',[Col2])),Upper('$map("sum([${Property}])", ",")'))>0,"Yes", "No" )
```

The thing here is when I select a value from the list box property viz. "TV | HDTV" then all those values from the Data Table start Coming up which are returning position viz. "TV | HD" , "TV | HDTV" both the values come up on the graph. Values get combined in the line which I do not want. Is there any way I can do an exact match or can this formula be tweaked.

I cannot change this flag to any other data type as around 30 calculations are based on this field.

Regards,

Subro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this on my own. I understood that the map function acts like a template. So I thought why not modify the template. Here is the code I used:

```
If(Upper(Concatenate([Col1],' | ',[Col2])) in ($map("'${Property}'", ",")),"Yes","No")
```

This works fine with my values. I checked it for many scenarios. Also for the property I used a field to populate it where in I have applied Upper so basically it holds already values which come in as Upper.
@niko: Thank you for your help. I am sure it would have worked too. Apologize for the time wasted on my behalf.

Regards,

Subro

Answer (score 1):

you could try a regex replace comparison:

```
If( RXReplace(Concatenate([Col1], ' | ', [Col2]), Concatenate('^', '$map("sum([${Property}])", ",")', '$'), "", "i") = "", "Yes", "No")
```

if the needle and haystack strings match, `RXReplace()` (I added the `"i"` to desensitize case) will return an empty string.

you *may* have to choose a different joining character besides the pipe, or you may have to concatenate with `"\\|"` if that's not possible.

Comment: Thank you @niko. I already figured it out. I used something a little more easier.

Comment: No problem! It would be great if you share your solution as an answer. I haven't seen many examples of `$map()` so it would be useful to see what you came up with :)